# mongodb query mixing timestamps and ISODates

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, isodate

I have a `mongodb` collection containing docs with both `ISODates` and `timestamps` in them, something like this:

```
doc = {
    "_id" : ObjectId(...),
    "updated" : 1445939778450,
    "delivered" : ISODate("2016-12-21T09:40:29.082Z")
    ...
}
```

how can I compare `updated` and `delivered` fields using $where?

Answer (score 0):

That's a great question! :)

It seems that `mongodb` handles this conversion automatically when using `$where`, so simply query like this:

```
db.my_collection.find({ $where : "this.updated > this.delivered" })
```

(if someone can point to documentation about this feature, please add)